# Regex to match comma separated string with no comma at the end of the line

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to write a regex that will allow input of all characters on the keyboard(even space) but will restrict the input of comma at the end of the line. I have tried do this,that includes all the possible characters,but it still does not give me the correct output:

```
   [RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z0-9\t\n ./<>?;:\"'!@#$%^&*()[]{}_+=|\\-]+,)*[a-zA-Z0-9\t\n ./<>?;:\"'!@#$%^&*()[]{}_+=|\\-]+$", ErrorMessage = "Comma is not allowed at the end of {0} ")]
```

Comment: Just use `(?<!,)$` at the end of your regex

Comment: @vks I dint get you.Do I have to use `(?<!,)$ ` with all characters or only `(?<!,)$ `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^.*[^,]$
```

.* means all char,don't need so long

Comment: can you tell me how does this work? you are using the escape sequence for both .* and , so how does it detect the , at the end of the line?

Comment: The `.` does not mean `all char` in your regex. Also, `^` and `$` can be ambiguous depending on the multiline flag used.

Comment: [^,] this match the any char except  ,

Comment: what if you don't want to allow spaces after `,` at the end of the line

Comment: @NaderHisham This still works,even if there are spaces after the comma,the code does exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: @nader-hisham  It just not allow the comma in the end, comma in other place will match .*   it match the comma and spaces

Answer (score 2):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\t\n ./<>?;:\"'!@#$%^&*()[]{}_+=|\\-]+,)*[a-zA-Z0-9\t\n ./<>?;:\"'!@#$%^&*()[]{}_+=|\\-]+(?<!,)$

                                                                                                        ^^
```

Just add `lookbehind` at the end.

Comment: You should probably explain what this is and why it works. I suspect it says "match anything the previous grouping does except the comma"

Comment: Is there a simpler way?Instead of explicitly writing all characters

Answer (score 0):

> a regex that will allow input of all characters on the keyboard(even space) but will restrict the input of comma at the end of the line.

Mind that you can type much more than what you typed using a keyboard. Basically, you want to allow *any* character *but* a comma at the end of the *line*.

So,

```
(?!,).(?=\r\n|\z)
```

This regex is checking each *line* (because of the `(?=\r\n|$)` look-ahead), and the `(?!,)` look-ahead makes sure the last character (that we match using `.`) is not a comma. `\z` is an unambiguous string end anchor.

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f!%2c).(%3f%3d%5cr%5cn%7c%5cz)&i=This+line+is+invalid%2c%0d%0aThis+line+is+valid%0d%0aThis+line+is+invalid%2c%0d%0aThis+line+is+valid)

This will work even on a client side.

To also get the full line match, you can just add `.*` at the beginning of the pattern (as we are not using singleline flag, `.` does not match newline symbols):

```
.*(?!,).(?=\r\n|\z)
```

Or (making it faster with an atomic group or an inline multiline option with `^` start of line anchor, but will not work on the client side)

```
(?>.*)(?!,).(?=\r\n|\z)
(?m)^.*?(?!,).(?=\r\n|\z) // The fastest of the last three
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*(%3f!%2c).(%3f%3d%5cr%5cn%7c%5cz)&i=This+line+is+invalid%2c%0d%0aThis+line+is+valid%0d%0aThis+line+is+invalid%2c%0d%0aThis+line+is+valid)